# creating new database entries and displaying using viewbags

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm unsure where my code is breaking. The cshtml page isn't displaying a ViewBag list. I don't know if its breaking when I add new participants to the list or when I call on the list to be displayed

Essentially what I want to do is make a list of basketball participants. If the list for a certain age group and gender doesn't exist my code should create the list then add the participant to it. If the list for the age group and gender already exists it would simply add the participant to that list.

What the code is doing:

- gets passing in an id
- if id matches an id of a participant, it check the gender of the participant
- check the age of the participant
- check if a league model exists for those criteria. If it doesn't, a new league model is created for that gender and age group
- create a new many-to-many model where participantId = the the id passed into the model and a leagueId = the id of the league model i just created
- however if the league model already exists for the age group/gender;  simply just add the many-to-many model

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("postNewBasketballPlayer")]
public IActionResult PostNewBasketballPlayer(int newParticipantId)
{
    ViewModel.Participant newP = db.Participants.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ParticipantId == newParticipantId);

    if (newP != null)
    {    
        var timespan = DateTime.Now - newP.ParticipantDOB;

        // this block of code is also repeated for newP.ParticipantGender == "Female"
        if (newP.ParticipantGender == "Male")
        {
             Console.WriteLine("Male basketball player");
             // this block of code repeats for different age groups
             if (timespan.TotalDays >= (7 * 365) && timespan.TotalDays < (9 * 365))
             {
                 League LeaguebbM7and8 = db.Leagues.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.gender == "Male" && i.ageRange == "7and8" && i.sport == "Basketball");

                 // if the League doesn't exist it creates it
                 if (LeaguebbM7and8 == null)
                 {
                     LeaguebbM7and8 = new League()
                     {
                         sport = "Basketball",
                         gender = "Male",
                         ageRange = "7and8"
                     };

                     db.Add(LeaguebbM7and8);
                     db.SaveChanges();

                     Console.WriteLine("made new league LeaguebbM7and8");

                     MMLeagueParticipant MMbbM7and8 = new MMLeagueParticipant()
                     {
                         ParticipantId = newParticipantId,
                         LeagueId = LeaguebbM7and8.LeagueId
                     };

                     // adds a row to table with the id's
                     db.Add(MMbbM7and8);
                     db.SaveChanges();

                     Console.WriteLine("added to LeaguebbM7and8");
                 }
                 // if the league exists; it simply adds it. 
                 else
                 {
                     // each time I add a child, it needs its own middle table (reason for new)
                     MMLeagueParticipant MMbbM7and8 = new MMLeagueParticipant()
                     {
                         ParticipantId = newParticipantId,
                         LeagueId = LeaguebbM7and8.LeagueId
                     };

                     db.Add(MMbbM7and8);
                     db.SaveChanges();

                     Console.WriteLine("added to LeaguebbM7and8");
                 }

                 Console.WriteLine("returning to dashboard (LeaguebbM7and8)");
                 return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
             }

             // this code is repeated for multiple age checks as above.
             // else if (timespan.TotalDays >= (9 * 365) && timespan.TotalDays < (11 * 365)){...}
             // else if (timespan.TotalDays >= (11 * 365) && timespan.TotalDays < (13 * 365)){...}
             // else if (timespan.TotalDays >= (13 * 365) && timespan.TotalDays < (15 * 365)){...}
             // else if (timespan.TotalDays >= (15 * 365) && timespan.TotalDays < (17 * 365)){...}
             // else if (timespan.TotalDays >= (17 * 365) && timespan.TotalDays < (19 * 365)){...}
         }

         // repeats the block of code above for all the age check if female.
         // if (newP.ParticipantGender == "Female)...
     }

     if (newP == null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("id passed in was null");
         return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
     }

     Console.WriteLine("skips all if checks because newP was   null");
     return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
}
```

What my terminal reads when LeaguebbM7and8 is null:

```
    newParticipantId
    15
    newP
    LeagueProject.Models.ViewModel+Participant
    Male basketball player
    made new league LeaguebbM7and8
    added to LeaguebbM7and8
    returning to dashboard (LeaguebbM7and8)
```

what my terminal reads when the list already exists for that gender and age group (LeageuebbM7and8 is not null):

```
newParticipantId
15
newP
LeagueProject.Models.ViewModel+Participant
Male basketball player
added to LeaguebbM7and8
returning to dashboard (LeaguebbM7and8)
```

My league model:

```
int LeagueId { get; set; }
string sport { get; set; }
string gender { get; set; }
string ageRange { get; set; }
​List<MMLeagueParticipant> allParticipants  { get; set; }        //(a many to many relationship for league and participant)
```

My ViewModel model:

```
public List<Participant> allParticipants { get; set; }
public ViewModel.Participant participant { get; set; }

public class Participant
{
    int ParticipantId { get; set; }
    string ParticipantFirstName { get; set; }
    string ParticipantLastName { get; set; }
    string ParticipantGender { get; set; }
    SystemDateTime ParticipantDOB { get; set; }
    List<MMLeagueParticipant> all Leagues { get; set; }
}
```

My MMLeagueParticipant middle table for the league model and ViewModel.Participant:

```
int MMLeaugeParticipantId { get; set; }
int ParticipantId { get; set; }
int LeaugeId { get; set; }
leauge sport { get; set; }
ViewModel.Participant child { get; set; }
```

Using the models listed above; I'm attempting to query and get the list of my participants by doing the following when calling the page i want to display:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("roster/basketball")]
public IActionResult BasketballRoster()
{
    //the reason im using viewbag is because its easier to work with since I can't pass multiple models in. and everything is in tabs. just makes life easier

    ViewBag.bbM7and8 = db.Leagues.Where(i=>i.sport == "Basketball" && i.ageRange == "7and8").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM7and8);

    ViewBag.bbM9and10 = db.Leagues.Where(i=>i.sport == "Basketball" && i.ageRange == "9and10").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM9and10);

    ViewBag.bbM11and12 = db.Leagues.Where(i=>i.sport == "Basketball" && i.ageRange == "11and12").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM11and12);

    ViewBag.bbM13and14 = db.Leagues.Where(i=>i.sport == "Basketball" && i.ageRange == "13and14").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM13and14);

    ViewBag.bbM15and16 = db.Leagues.Where(i=>i.sport == "Basketball" && i.ageRange == "15and16").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM15and16);

    ViewBag.bbM17and18 = db.Leagues.Where(i=>i.sport == "Basketball" && i.ageRange == "17and18").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM17and18);

    return View("RosterPageBasketball");
}
```

what the console.WriteLine(ViewBag.bbM7and8) displays in the terminal:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LeagueProject.Models.League]
```

My rosterpage contains different tabs. Each of tab displays "ViewBag.bbM#and#"(with their respected age group) and "test 1"

```
            //cshtml

            <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM7and8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM7and8-tab">
                    7-8
                    @{
                        var hasData=false;
                        //checks if list is null
                        if(ViewBag.bbM7and8 != null)
                        {
                            <p>test: ViewBag.bbM7and8 is not null</p>
                            @foreach(League j in ViewBag.bbM7and8)
                            {
                                <p>test 1: foreach</p>
                                @if( j.allParticipants != null) 
                                {
                                    <p>test 2: null</p>
                                    @foreach(MMLeagueParticipant mmLp in j.allParticipants)
                                    {
                                        <p>test 3: foreach</p>
                                        @if( mmLp.child != null) 
                                        {
                                            p>test 4: null</p>
                                            hasData=true;
                                            <p>@mmLp.child.ParticipantFirstName @mmLp.child.ParticipantLastName</p>
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                @if( j.allParticipants == null)
                                {
                                    <p>league model is null</p>
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @if(!hasData)
                            {
                                <p>the list is empty</p>
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </div>
                //the above code is repeated for each tab
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM9and10" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM9and10-tab"></div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM11and12" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM11and12-tab"></div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM13and14" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM13and14-tab"></div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM15and16" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM15and16-tab"></div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bbM17and18" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="bbM17and18-tab"></div>
```

what the page displays:

```
test b
7-8
test: ViewBag.bbM7and8 is not null

test 1: foreach
league model is null
```

doesn't get to test 3. Meaning each league in the ViewBag is null. This leads me to believe the issue perhaps is with how I may be creating and or adding onto the league model. Everything looks fine to me. Just need a second pair of eyes.

note: I should have 2 participants in this viewbag.

what i tried:

- i tried putting both foreaches under the else to see if I could do this inversely.
- - error: RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
    RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: Why are you using the untyped `ViewBag` instead of the strongly-typed `Model`?

Comment: can't pass in multiple models from my conroller

Comment: "can't pass in multiple models from my controller" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: you can only use one model for each cshtml page. My "roster/basketball" route I would only be able to return one model; and my page is broken up in tabs that need their own list.

Comment: "you can only use one model for each cshtml pag" - **That's not true**. You do indeed need to define an aggregate type for the whole page/view, but that aggregae can contain multiple objects. You can also have multiple `<form>` elements on the same page/view that post different _root objects_ by using `ModelExpression` directly instead of `asp-for`.

Comment: oh I see, as a wrapper. My brain think about doing it that way since I'm fairly new to c#. But at this point that would require a lot of restructuring in my code. I don't understand why my league j in ViewBag.bbM7and8 is null.  I restructured my If's in my cshtml to better follow along. Assuming from the way I was taught It should still work this way even though it may be a bit repetitive.

Comment: So the problem is `allParticipants == null` - but I don't see anywhere in your code where you're loading or setting `allParticipants`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your code is not explicitly loading `allParticipants`.

Entity Framework and Linq-to-Entities do not *magically* load an entire object-graph from the database - you need to tell it *when* and *what* to load.

Also, you should always prefer Explicit Loading and disable EF's Lazy Loading feature - this is because the *modern* (and correct) way of doing things means you must not perform any IO inside property getters (because side-effects are bad, and IO generally involves `async`/`await` and you can't use `await` inside a property-getter).

You can also greatly simplify your logic to load all Basketball `League` entities given a list of `AgeRange` values, which I've done-so below, in addition to my code that explicitly loads all relevant `MMLeagueParticipants` and `Participants` entities:

Change your loading code to this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

[HttpGet]
[Route("roster/basketball")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBasketballRoster()
{
    String[] leagueNames = new[]
    {
        "7and8",
        "9and10",
        "11and12",
        "13and14",
        "15and16",
        "17and18"
    };

#if NEVER_DO_THIS

    // The *bad* way is to load the Leagues then manually load each League's participants individually - this will result in `1 + M` queries, or even `1 + M + ( M * P )` queries.

    List<League> bbLeagues = await db.Leagues
        .Where( l => l.Sport == "Basketball" )
        .Where( l => leagueNames.Contains( l.AgeRange ) )
        .ToListAsync();    

    
    foreach( League league in bbLeagues )
    {
        /*
        await db.Entry( league )
            .Collection( l => l.AllParticipants )
            .LoadAsync(); // Note this will not load `Participant`.
        */

        // This code does load `Participant` but we need to use `Query()`, but when you use `Query` EF isn't smart enough to know how to track the entities in-memory, so you need to manually add everything:

        List<MMLeagueParticipants> leagueParticipants = await db.Entry( league )
            .Collection( l => l.AllParticipants )
            .Query() // <-- This is needed to allow for `Include()`
            .Include( mmp => mmp.Participant )
            .ToListAsync();

        // Need to do this because EF won't do it for us when using `Query()`:
        league.AllParticipants.AddRange( leagueParticipants );
    }

#else

    // A better approach is to batch-load each entity (Leagues, MMLeagueParticipants, and Participants), resulting in only 3 queries:
    
    List<League> bbLeagues = await db.Leagues
        .Where( l => l.Sport == "Basketball" )
        .Where( l => leagueNames.Contains( l.AgeRange ) )
        .ToListAsync();    

    List<MMLeagueParticipants> links;
    if( true /* Using a manual JOIN: */ )
    {
        
        List<Int32> leagueIds = bbLeagues.Select( l => l.LeagueId ).ToList();

        links = await db.MMLeagueParticipants
            .Where( mmp => leagueIds.Contains( mmp.LeagueId ) )
            .ToListAsync();
    }
    else // Using a DB JOIN, assuming your Navigation Properties are configured correctly:
    {
        links = await db.MMLeagueParticipants
            .Where( mmp => mmp.League.Sport == "Basketball" )
            .Where( mmp => leagueNames.Contains( mmp.League.AgeRange ) )
            .ToListAsync();
    }

    List<Int32> participantIds = participants
        .Select( p => p.ParticipantId )
        .Distinct() // <-- This step prevents duplicate results.
        .ToList();

    List<Participant> participants = await db.Participants
        .Where( p => participantIds.Contains( p => p.ParticipantId ) )
        .ToListAsync();

    //

#endif

    // NOTE: Entity Framework automagically "loads" entities it reads from the database directly into the DbContext *and other loaded entities*, so after the above manual loading then all of the `League` objects will have correctly-populated `Participants` collections - but here's an assertion anyway:
    if( participants.Count > 0 && bbLeagues.All( l => l.AllParticipants == null || l.AllParticipants.Count() == 0 )
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException( "No participants collections were updated by Entity Framework after loading participants. Is your model configured correctly?" );
    }

    IReadOnlyDictionary< String, League > leaguesDict = bbLeagues.ToDictionary( l => l.AgeRange );

    RosterPageViewModel pageViewModel = new RosterPageViewModel( leaguesDict );

    return View( "RosterPageBasketball", pageViewModel );
}

public class RosterPageViewModel
{
    public RosterPageViewModel(
        IReadOnlyDictionary< String, League > leagues
    )
    {
        this.Leagues = leagues ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(leagues));
    }

    public IReadOnlyDictionary< String, League > Leagues { get; }
}
```

Comment: I tried the first example. But my list was getting duplicated until i commented out the "league.allParticipants.AddRange( leagueParticipants );" line. another issue that came up was that my list for 7and8 is being displayed for all the age groups. The second solution wouldn't work because of missing returns. The last solution gave me the error error CS1026: ) expected [C:\Users\jaski\Desktop\CodingDojo\Dojo_Assignments\projects\c#Projects\LeagueProject\LeagueProject.csproj]. for the if line.